# For Android is there an example of controls outside list view?

Tags: android, listview

```html
<!-- test.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_location_table_layout_results">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/button_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragmenttab1_item_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Help" >
    </Button>

</FrameLayout>
```

I have not found example like this so not sure what I need to do is possible.

I need to open up a dialog that has multiple fragments and on one of those fragments have a textview with button that when the button is selected it

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_location_table_layout_results"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fragmenttab1_item_edittext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <Button android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/fragmenttab1_search_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Search"
        style="WW3dBaseTheme" />

</TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/test"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_location_table_layout_results" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

populates a listview of buttons that is shown below the textview/button on the same fragment.

Is that possible? I tried but for some reason instead of just the list of buttons I get copies of the textview/button pair and the button I want in the listview. It is almost as if because I have the listview in the xml it pulls in all the ui controls when it renders inside the listview. Here is the xml>

Comment: Added snippet for test.xml. Sorry still trying to figure out how to edit posts here.

Answer (score 0):

As I expected it turned out I needed to put the xml for control for the listview in another xml file in order to draw properly in the list.